# How can I install a custom (patched) PECL extension?

Tags: php, centos, pecl

I'm trying to use the htscanner PECL extension on my CentOS 5/PHP 5.2.6 machine, but there's a bug in the latest version where a newline character is added to the end of every `php_value` directive.  This behavior causes my `include_path` and `error_log` values not to work.

The bug and the patch are documented on the PECL site:
http://pecl.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=16891

I've downloaded the latest version, applied the patch, and re-compressed the package — but I can't get the PECL installer to accept it — or any local package, for that matter.

I've tried every variation of the `pecl install` syntax that I can think of, and the only times I'm able to get it to work, it downloads an online copy first and ignores the local copy.

Can anyone recommend a method for installing a PECL extension from a local file?  Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have the (patched) extension source code locally you can bypass PECL entirely:

```
# cd extension_dir
# phpize
# ./configure
# make
# make install
```

(`phpize` is a binary that comes with PHP - It prepares the extension to be compiled, the rest is pretty straightforward).

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  One note: `phpize && ./configure --enable-htscanner && make` — I added `--enable-htscanner` as per the included README.