# Can't seem to install imagick

Tags: linux, arch-linux, pecl, imagemagick

I'm trying to install the PHP PEAR PECL extension "imagick" (image magick), but failing horribly.  It seems that I keed installing packages to progress, but this one has me stumped.  It seems to fail all the way at the bottom.

**Please Note: I'm using ArchLinux, apt-get doesn't save me.**

```
[root@Crux tmp]# pecl install imagick
downloading imagick-3.0.1.tgz ...
Starting to download imagick-3.0.1.tgz (93,920 bytes)
.....................done: 93,920 bytes
13 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20100412
Zend Module Api No:      20100525
Zend Extension Api No:   220100525
Please provide the prefix of Imagemagick installation [autodetect] :
building in /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootLbSUWT/imagick-3.0.1
running: /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/configure --with-imagick
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php/modules
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... re2c
checking for re2c version... 0.13.5 (ok)
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether to enable the imagick extension... yes, shared
checking whether to enable the imagick GraphicsMagick backend... no
checking ImageMagick MagickWand API configuration program... found in /usr/bin/MagickWand-config
checking if ImageMagick version is at least 6.2.4... found version 6.7.8 Q16
checking for MagickWand.h header file... found in /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h
checking PHP version is at least 5.1.3... yes. found 5.4.6
checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no

creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
running: make
/bin/sh /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootLbSUWT/imagick-3.0.1/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/imagick -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootLbSUWT/imagick-3.0.1/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootLbSUWT/imagick-3.0.1/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/imagick -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/ImageMagick  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c -o imagick_class.lo
mkdir .libs
 cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/imagick -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootLbSUWT/imagick-3.0.1/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootLbSUWT/imagick-3.0.1/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/imagick -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/ImageMagick -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/imagick_class.o
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function âzim_imagick_getimagematteâ:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:268:2: warning: âMagickGetImageMatteâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:82) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function âzim_imagick_getsizeoffsetâ:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:406:2: warning: passing argument 2 of âMagickGetSizeOffsetâ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h:73:0,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick.h:49,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:21:
/usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/magick-property.h:87:3: note: expected âssize_t *â but argument is of type âlong int *â
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function âzim_imagick_paintfloodfillimageâ:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:1016:3: warning: âMagickPaintFloodfillImageâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:99) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:1019:3: warning: âMagickPaintFloodfillImageâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:99) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function âzim_imagick_getimagepropertiesâ:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:1083:2: warning: passing argument 3 of âMagickGetImagePropertiesâ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h:73:0,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick.h:49,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:21:
/usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/magick-property.h:35:5: note: expected âsize_t *â but argument is of type âlong unsigned int *â
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function âzim_imagick_getimageprofilesâ:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:1131:2: warning: passing argument 3 of âMagickGetImageProfilesâ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h:73:0,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick.h:49,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:21:
/usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/magick-property.h:33:5: note: expected âsize_t *â but argument is of type âlong unsigned int *â
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function âzim_imagick_recolorimageâ:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:1402:2: warning: âMagickRecolorImageâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:109) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function âzim_imagick_setfontâ:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:1442:3: error: âstruct _php_core_globalsâ has no member named âsafe_modeâ
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:1442:3: error: âCHECKUID_CHECK_FILE_AND_DIRâ undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:1442:3: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:1442:3: error: âCHECKUID_NO_ERRORSâ undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function âzim_imagick_queryformatsâ:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:2580:2: warning: passing argument 2 of âMagickQueryFormatsâ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h:73:0,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick.h:49,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:21:
/usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/magick-property.h:41:5: note: expected âsize_t *â but argument is of type âlong unsigned int *â
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function âzim_imagick_queryfontsâ:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:2607:2: warning: passing argument 2 of âMagickQueryFontsâ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h:73:0,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick.h:49,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:21:
/usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/magick-property.h:40:5: note: expected âsize_t *â but argument is of type âlong unsigned int *â
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function âzim_imagick_colorfloodfillimageâ:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:3396:2: warning: âMagickColorFloodfillImageâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:75) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function âzim_imagick_mapimageâ:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:3730:2: warning: âMagickMapImageâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:86) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function âzim_imagick_mattefloodfillimageâ:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:3763:2: warning: âMagickMatteFloodfillImageâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:88) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function âzim_imagick_medianfilterimageâ:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:3790:2: warning: âMagickMedianFilterImageâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/magick-image.h:217) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function âzim_imagick_paintopaqueimageâ:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:3853:2: warning: âMagickPaintOpaqueImageChannelâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:104) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function âzim_imagick_painttransparentimageâ:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:3916:2: warning: âMagickPaintTransparentImageâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:107) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function âzim_imagick_reducenoiseimageâ:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:4059:2: warning: âMagickReduceNoiseImageâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/magick-image.h:266) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function âzim_imagick_getimageattributeâ:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:5068:2: warning: âMagickGetImageAttributeâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:59) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function âzim_imagick_getimagechannelextremaâ:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:5253:2: warning: âMagickGetImageChannelExtremaâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:78) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:5253:2: warning: passing argument 3 of âMagickGetImageChannelExtremaâ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h:68:0,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick.h:49,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:21:
/usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:78:3: note: expected âsize_t *â but argument is of type âlong unsigned int *â
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:5253:2: warning: passing argument 4 of âMagickGetImageChannelExtremaâ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h:68:0,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick.h:49,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:21:
/usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:78:3: note: expected âsize_t *â but argument is of type âlong unsigned int *â
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function âzim_imagick_getimageextremaâ:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:5506:2: warning: âMagickGetImageExtremaâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:80) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:5506:2: warning: passing argument 2 of âMagickGetImageExtremaâ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h:68:0,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick.h:49,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:21:
/usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:80:3: note: expected âsize_t *â but argument is of type âlong unsigned int *â
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:5506:2: warning: passing argument 3 of âMagickGetImageExtremaâ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h:68:0,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick.h:49,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:21:
/usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:80:3: note: expected âsize_t *â but argument is of type âlong unsigned int *â
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function âzim_imagick_getimagehistogramâ:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:5629:2: warning: passing argument 2 of âMagickGetImageHistogramâ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h:74:0,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick.h:49,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:21:
/usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/magick-image.h:415:5: note: expected âsize_t *â but argument is of type âlong unsigned int *â
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function âzim_imagick_getimagepageâ:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:5740:2: warning: passing argument 2 of âMagickGetImagePageâ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h:74:0,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick.h:49,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:21:
/usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/magick-image.h:192:3: note: expected âsize_t *â but argument is of type âlong unsigned int *â
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:5740:2: warning: passing argument 3 of âMagickGetImagePageâ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h:74:0,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick.h:49,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:21:
/usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/magick-image.h:192:3: note: expected âsize_t *â but argument is of type âlong unsigned int *â
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:5740:2: warning: passing argument 4 of âMagickGetImagePageâ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h:74:0,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick.h:49,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:21:
/usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/magick-image.h:192:3: note: expected âssize_t *â but argument is of type âlong int *â
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:5740:2: warning: passing argument 5 of âMagickGetImagePageâ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h:74:0,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick.h:49,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:21:
/usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/magick-image.h:192:3: note: expected âssize_t *â but argument is of type âlong int *â
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function âzim_imagick_getimageindexâ:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:6344:2: warning: âMagickGetImageIndexâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:65) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function âzim_imagick_setimageindexâ:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:6369:2: warning: âMagickSetImageIndexâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:113) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function âzim_imagick_getimagesizeâ:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:6447:2: warning: âMagickGetImageSizeâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:140) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function âzim_imagick_setimageattributeâ:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:6796:2: warning: âMagickSetImageAttributeâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:111) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function âzim_imagick_flattenimagesâ:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:7043:2: warning: âMagickFlattenImagesâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:132) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function âzim_imagick_averageimagesâ:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:8079:2: warning: âMagickAverageImagesâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:131) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function âzim_imagick_mosaicimagesâ:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:8516:2: warning: âMagickMosaicImagesâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/deprecate.h:135) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function âzim_imagick_getpageâ:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:9126:2: warning: passing argument 2 of âMagickGetPageâ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h:73:0,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick.h:49,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:21:
/usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/magick-property.h:84:3: note: expected âsize_t *â but argument is of type âlong int *â
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:9126:2: warning: passing argument 3 of âMagickGetPageâ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h:73:0,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick.h:49,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:21:
/usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/magick-property.h:84:3: note: expected âsize_t *â but argument is of type âlong int *â
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:9126:2: warning: passing argument 4 of âMagickGetPageâ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h:73:0,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick.h:49,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:21:
/usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/magick-property.h:84:3: note: expected âssize_t *â but argument is of type âlong int *â
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:9126:2: warning: passing argument 5 of âMagickGetPageâ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h:73:0,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick.h:49,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:21:
/usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/magick-property.h:84:3: note: expected âssize_t *â but argument is of type âlong int *â
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function âzim_imagick_getquantumdepthâ:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:9154:2: warning: passing argument 1 of âMagickGetQuantumDepthâ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h:73:0,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick.h:49,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:21:
/usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/magick-property.h:52:4: note: expected âsize_t *â but argument is of type âlong int *â
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function âzim_imagick_getquantumrangeâ:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:9176:2: warning: passing argument 1 of âMagickGetQuantumRangeâ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h:73:0,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick.h:49,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:21:
/usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/magick-property.h:53:4: note: expected âsize_t *â but argument is of type âlong int *â
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function âzim_imagick_getsamplingfactorsâ:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:9247:2: warning: passing argument 2 of âMagickGetSamplingFactorsâ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h:73:0,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick.h:49,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:21:
/usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/magick-property.h:59:4: note: expected âsize_t *â but argument is of type âlong int *â
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function âzim_imagick_getsizeâ:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:9273:2: warning: passing argument 2 of âMagickGetSizeâ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h:73:0,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick.h:49,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:21:
/usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/magick-property.h:86:3: note: expected âsize_t *â but argument is of type âlong unsigned int *â
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:9273:2: warning: passing argument 3 of âMagickGetSizeâ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h:73:0,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick.h:49,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:21:
/usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/magick-property.h:86:3: note: expected âsize_t *â but argument is of type âlong unsigned int *â
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function âzim_imagick_getversionâ:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:9299:2: warning: passing argument 1 of âMagickGetVersionâ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h:73:0,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick.h:49,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:21:
/usr/include/ImageMagick/wand/magick-property.h:55:4: note: expected âsize_t *â but argument is of type âlong int *â
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c: In function âzim_imagick_setimageprogressmonitorâ:
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:9534:2: error: âstruct _php_core_globalsâ has no member named âsafe_modeâ
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:9534:2: error: âCHECKUID_CHECK_FILE_AND_DIRâ undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_class.c:9534:2: error: âCHECKUID_NO_ERRORSâ undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [imagick_class.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest either installing from the [aur php-imagick package](http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=30008) or taking a look at it, arch's `php` is patched a bit. I just installed the aur package without a problem.

If the aur package fails for you, let the author know. The issue is almost absolutely caused by not having a version of the imagick extension that is in line with your php version -- the error about `_php_core_globals has no member named safe_mode` relates to a misfeature that was removed in 5.4.

Comment: Yes, it is caused by php 5.4. See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61501 for a version of imagick that is claimed to work with 5.4.

Comment: I'm running 5.4.6, the aur build uses imagick 3.0.1 and this patch: http://sprunge.us/gWGZ

Comment: thanks for the help guys.  Unfortunately I'm a pretty big noob, I tried to run, tar, patch, then did this: http://serverfault.com/questions/219570/how-can-i-install-a-custom-patched-pecl-extension

And it built I think, but it still fails to install properly, IE the phpinfo file doesn't show it.  What did I do wrong?

Comment: You probably just need to uncomment the line in `/etc/php/conf.d/imagick.ini` and restart apache (or whatever server you're using).

Comment: Or add it to the extensions line in `/etc/php/php.ini`, since you seem to have installed it via PECL as opposed to the AUR package. Or whatever `php.ini` your php is using. In short, you probably just need a `extension=imagick.so` line somewhere.

Comment: Haha! Success!  I <3 you man.  Nice bio BTW: "I really enjoy automating things that can be automated, and in general feel that humans shouldn't have to do things that robots can do unless they really want to."  Amen to that.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is fixed in 3.1.0RC1 and 3.1.0RC2, but those are still beta (at the present time), so if you're getting this error, it's probably trying to install imagick 3.0.1 which has this problem.  So instead of using "pecl install imagick", get the beta version instead:

```
 pecl install imagick-beta
```